# How are the intermediate values between observations in time series calculated in ts() in R?

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, arima

I need help regarding how `frequency` affects my time series. I fit a daily time series data with `frequency = 7` When I view the time series, I get intermediate values between days. I have data for ***60 days***. I created a time series for the same

```
 ts.v1<-  ts(V1, start = as.Date("2017-08-01"), end = as.Date("2017-09-30"), frequency = 7)
```

which gives me ***421 values***. I kind of understood that it has to do with the `frequency` as the value is a product of 7 and 60. What I need to know is- how are these calculated? And why? Isn't `frequency` used only to tell your time series whether the data is daily/weekly/annual etc.? (I referred to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120806/frequency-value-for-seconds-minutes-intervals-data-in-r))

Similarly in my `ACF` and `PACF` plots, the `lag` values are < 1 meaning there are seven values to make 1 'lag'. In that scenario, when I estimate `arima(p,d,q)` using these plots would the values be taken as lag x frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally one does not use Date class with ts.  With ts, the frequency is the number of points in a unit interval.  Just use:

```
ts(V1, frequency = 7)
```

The times will be 1, 1 + 1/7, 1 + 2/7, ...   You can later match them to the proper dates if need be.

Comment: If `st` and `en` are your start and end `"Date"` class dates then it will use `seq(as.numeric(st), as.numeric(en), 1/7)` as the times and fill in the values using `V1` recycling as necessary to fill it out to the full length.